# After compiling a release version my application is started acting weird

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I made an application in Visual Studio 2010 Express. First i compiled a debug version, and it worked perfectely, but after compiling a release version it freezes.
My application should work like this:
I have collected the BIOS version to all desktop, and it will automacially update bios versions. They are located on a Network share like \myserver\bios_update. There is also a Log folder in \\myserver\bios_update\Log. My application will create a log file in this log folder in the following way: \\myserver\bios_update\log\OptiPlex 780\hostname.txt Of course OptiPlex 780 is the PC's Model type, and if it doesn't exist, it will be created because there are many PC Model Types. If the hostname.txt(hostname is substituted with the computers hostname) doesn't exist, it will be also created.

The interesting part is, that for now it worked fine, but after compiling a release version, my application is acting the following way. If the hostname.txt exists, then it is working fine, but if not then it will freeze. It is like it's going in an infinite loop, but i don't know why(i printed some data and i know thats why i said an infinite loop).

I noticed the following things:
Here will my application freeze : if ( folderexists( LogFolder ) )
LogFolder contains a path like \\myserver\bios_update\Log\ 
If the hostname.txt doesn't exists, my app will freeze, but if it exists, then it's fine. Also if i give LogFolder without the last \ like \myserver\bios_update\Log then it is also fine.
Here is my code:

```
bool folderexists( char * foldername )
{
if ( _access( foldername, 0 ) == 0 )
  { 
    struct stat status;
    stat( foldername, &status );

    if ( status.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
    {           
        //cout << "\nThe directory exists." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "\nThe path you entered is a file." << endl;
        WriteToLog( "The path you entered is a file??????????????????", false );
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    //cout << "\nPath doesn't exist." << endl;
    return false;
}
}//folderexists


void WriteToLog( char * text, bool star )
{
char time[ SMALL ], LogModel[ MEDIUM ], Day[ SMALL ], Month[ SMALL ];
FILE *logfile;

memset( time, 0, sizeof( time ) );
memset( Day, 0, sizeof( Day ) );
memset( Month, 0, sizeof( Month ) );

SYSTEMTIME lt;

GetLocalTime( &lt );

GetDayAndMonth( lt.wDayOfWeek , Day, lt.wMonth, Month );

sprintf( time, "[%s %s %d %02d:%02d:%02d]", Day, Month, lt.wDay, lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond );

//printf("\nThe local time is: %02d:%02d\n", lt.wHour, lt.wMinute);

if ( !file_exists( LogFile ) )
{
    memset( LogModel, 0, sizeof( LogModel ) );
    strcpy( LogModel, LogFolder );
    strcat( LogModel, PCModel );

    if ( folderexists( LogFolder ) ) <== Here is where my App freeze!!!!!!!
    {
        if ( !folderexists( LogModel ) )
        {
            if ( !CreateDirectoryA( LogModel, NULL ) ) ShowError( "CreateDirectoryA .............................. Failed! ( creating LogModel folder ) ", true, true );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nLogFolder isn't reachable!" ); 
        exit(-1);
    }
}//file_exists

if ( ( logfile = fopen( LogFile, "a" ) ) == NULL ) 
{
    ShowError( "Failed to create Logfile!", false, true );
}
else 
{
    fputs( time, logfile );
    fputs( " - ", logfile );
    fputs( text, logfile );
    fputs( "\n", logfile );
    if ( star ) fputs( "**********************************************************************************************************************\n", logfile );

    fclose( logfile );

    //if ( star ) exit( -1 );
}
}//WriteToLog
```

Any advice appritiated because it's driving me crazy and i can't figure it out, what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is calling itself recursively. In FolderExists you call WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog which calls if FolderExists which calls WriteToLog .... etc

Comment: Damn! You are right! How could i miss this? But this is only part of my problem. I don't understand, why it was working in the debug version, and why it is not working in the release version? If i give LogFolder with a \ at the end then it won't find the driectory, but in thedbug version it did find.

Comment: @kampi I was hoping you wouldn't ask the question about Debug/Release differences :) I'm not a C/C++ guy so I have no idea how release and debug would change this behavior

Comment: Sorry :) But i'm going crazy. Folderexists return "The path you entered is a file" almost every time, and i don't know why :(

Comment: Maybe sprintf or cout the foldername in FolderExists to see how it is concatenated. Are you 100% sure all your * ** &* are in the correct place? :-)

Comment: @rene yes i am :) Until i compiled a debug it everything worked fine, so it has to be correct everywhere. I print in folderexists the directory name, but if hostname.txt doesn't exists folderexists will return false because "the path you entered is a file". Maybe i should look for another method to check if a folder exists or not?

Comment: @kampi did you try putting a cout in FolderExtsts for the pointer foldername? My guess is that somewhere your app is writing outside a memory structure

Comment: @rene: yes i did put a cout and it is ok

Comment: @kampi is maybe the mvcrt.dll version linked (or something) diffeent for release? Looks like the stat function is behaving differently.

Comment: @rene i don't know, but in the meantime i have rewritten my folderexists() and now it is working fine. I use now :   dwAttrs = GetFileAttributesA( foldername );
     if ( dwAttrs == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES ) return false;
     else return true;